# Intuition for almost sure convergence = fast enough convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I know the meaning of convergence in probability and almost convergence. From zero-one law, we can derive that if a sequence of random variables converges in probability fast enough, then it converges almost surely.

Is there any intuitive real example that can illustrate this theorem?

Comment: What is the 0-1 law you refer to? What do you mean by "fast enough"?

Comment: The simplest example might be to consider independent sequences $(X_n)$ of Bernoulli random variables with $P(X_n=1)=x_n$, $P(X_n=0)=1-x_n$ and $x_n\to0$. Thus $X_n\to0$ in probability, always, but $X_n\to0$ almost surely if and only if the series $\sum_nx_n$ converges. Thus, "fast enough".

Comment: On the other hand, there is no equivalence in the sense that, for every $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to0$ there exists $(X_n)$ such that $X_n\to0$ almost surely but $P(|X_n|>1)>x_n$ for every $n$ large enough. Thus the almost sure convergence can hold with the rate of the convergence in probability being as slow as one wants.

Comment: @Did why $ x_{n} → 0$? on your first comment